# NetBeans- Java Fx(mobile) could'n buld the projecjt

Tags: netbeans, java

I have an error in NetBeans(mobile business application)
I have installed JDK (latest version jdk1.6.0_21)
After this I had an error:

```
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javac.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Then in "Advanced system settings"->Environment variables 
I added a new line in "system variables" - "JAVA_HOME" ,value - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21 (my path to JDK)

Then i had "unknown error" 
See in the screen..->

http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/6423/screencc.png' border='0' width="300px" height="300px"> or url http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/6423/screencc.png
Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is specific to your machine setup.  `javac` is the Java compiler, but it's looking for it inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\`.

Let's try to dig through this:

1. Did you uninstall your previous JDK after you installed JDK6u21?
2. Did you uninstall your JRE?
3. What OS are you running?  Windows 7 64?
4. Go to your Add/Remove Programs.  You need the following entries:

[image]

1. What do you have in your `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\`?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you have to install both the 32-bit and 64-bit version of the JDK.